# Which IDE do you use for Mathematica development?

Tags: development

After more than a year I revisited the IntelliJIDEA plugin but that still seems to be 'just' an editor, of course there is the Mathematica Workbench but why are there so few improvements? Version 10. code like

```
 dataset = Dataset[{
 <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {1}|>,
 <|"a" -> 6, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {}|>}]
```

is not accepted by the Workbench 2 editor which was built for version 7. The standard Mathematica package editor doesn't feel like a real editor. So. Am i missing something? - What do you use for developing somewhat larger packages?

Comment: While I'm sure many of us will have views, this is primarily opinion-based. Unless the community feels otherwise, we will probably have to close this question on those grounds. Could you perhaps redraft your question to be more consistent with the StackExchange model for "Answerable" questions? See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask Alternatively, you could try asking in chat?

Comment: @Verbeia personally, I would be tempted to ignore that restriction in this case. One can see why asking opinion-based questions is discouraged in general, but in practice we have so few of these that it can hardly be seen as a problem. Here, well-defined and justified personal preferences and some amount of experience are certainly necessary for an answer to be useful. I would be especially interested in knowing how this is approached inside WRI. Of course, it is up to everyone to vote according to their interpretation of whether this thread will produce useful answers.

Comment: Is answering which editor you use, opinion based??! I am not asking a judgment on any of the available products.

Comment: @ndroock1 It is exactly the kind if question described in the first bulleted list on the [**don't ask** page](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).  Nevertheless for the time being I shall respect Oleksandr's recommendation and leave this open; let's see how it develops.

Comment: I don't understand Wizard, I just want to know what you lot use to develop your code with. Very simple question. Ask this question in a java crowd and you get a list of editors in use in the community.

Comment: @ndroock1 I know it's a simple question.  The problem is that there is no "right" answer so it falls into the subjective category, but that's OK sometimes, and our site is a bit looser with that requirement than other Stack Exchange chapters.  However you should be aware of the intended limitations of the Q&A model used here when writing your questions.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - My answer would be: "I use the Wolfram Workbench because it has MUnit but it frustrates me that it is not improved by Wolfram ( are they working on something new? )." - They might count on the community to enhance the IntelliJIDEA plugin. IntelliJIDEA is arguably the best IDE around for many, if not at all languages. Others may use text editors, or code in the Notebook. - These are all right answers, imho.

Comment: @ndroock1 You'll notice the question remains open.  Again our site is more relaxed about the subjective/open-ended question rule.  However I also wish to point out that Verbeia's perspective is spelled out in the written Stack Exchange guidelines.  Questions like this are often best judged by the answers they produce; I must say I am surprised that this one has no answers yet.

Comment: I am too @Mr.Wizard considering it has six upvotes. I am thinking of reformulating the question in terms of development -workflow- for making Mathematica software. Perhaps I think too much like a programmer while the vast majority of Mma users are scientists.

Comment: It would be a usefule Q&A in one case: the answer(s) would provide the pros and cons (as objectively as possible) of the different IDE-s in a comparable way, so anyone could decide on hes/her own judgement which is the best suiting IDE for him/her.

Comment: I have voted (in the review queue) to leave this question open.  A major problem with **primarily opinion-based** questions is that they can engender too many answers, however this has *no* answers at this time so it is hardly problematic in that way.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, considering I don't have the privilege to be able to work all the time with ( our beloved ) Mathematica, I only recently installed Workbench 3. From a WB3 perspective my question seems irrelevant. Although I own an IntelliJ Ultimate License, the IntelliJ plugin for Mma does not even come close to WB3. - But yes, during Version 10 and early Version 11, Wolfram wasn't very kind to the WB community by leaving out support for major new features.

Comment: @nilo Self-answer perhaps, given the experience you now have?