# Solution for multiple cursors to perform multiple simultaneous edits

Tags: front-end, keyboard

Is there any good solution available for performing multiple edits simultaneously in a Mathematica notebook?

As a workaround, I occasionally paste Mathematica code into a Visual Studio Code editor, perform various multiple-cursor edits, and then paste the result back into the Mathematica notebook. The Mathematica technique seems to be Find (interestingly there's no support for the standard UI metaphor of CTRL+H Replace -- but one gets used to it). However, Find and Replace with a popup dialog is rather cumbersome compared to ease of multi-editing. In VS Code for example, press CTRL+L to select all instances of the currently selected text and start typing to overwrite. Many other editors also support multi-cursor editing.

I suspect the answer is *no*, there isn't a native solution for multi-editing. Nevertheless, I'll pose the question in the hope of being pleasantly surprised.

Comment: Take a look at: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86799/which-ide-do-you-use-for-mathematica-development  (which doesn't have an answer, but has some background info. you might find useful).

Comment: You can do that with http://wlplugin.halirutan.de/, does it qualify as an answer?